# IGNORE DATA IN SAS IMPORT FROM EXCEL

Tags: sas

I have no working knowledge of SAS, but I have an excel file that I need to import and work with. In the excel file there are about 100 rows (observations) and 7 columns (quantities). In some cases, a particular observation may not have any data in one column. I need to completely ignore that observation when reading my data into SAS. I'm wondering what the commands for this would be.

An obvious cheap solution would be to delete the rows in the excel file with missing data, but I want to do this with SAS commands, because I want to learn some SAS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Import the data however you want, for example with the IMPORT procedure, as Stig Eide mentioned.

```
proc import
    datafile = 'C:\...\file.xlsx'
    dbms = xlsx
    out = xldata
    replace;
    mixed = YES;
    getnames = YES;
run;
```

Explanation:

- The DBMS= option specifies how SAS will try to read the data. If your file is an Excel 2007+ file, i.e. xlsx, then you can use DBMS=XLSX as shown here. If your file is older, e.g. xls rather than xlsx, try DBMS=EXCEL.
- The OUT= option names the output dataset.

  - If a single level name is specified, the dataset is written to the WORK library. That's the temporary library that's unique to each SAS session. It gets deleted when the session ends.
  - To create a permanent dataset, specify a two level name, like mylib.xldata, where mylib refers to a SAS library reference (libref) created with a LIBNAME statement.
- REPLACE replaces the dataset created the first time you run this step.
- MIXED=YES tells SAS that the data may be of mixed types.
- GETNAMES=YES will name your SAS dataset variables based on the column names in Excel.

If I understand you correctly, you want to remove every observation in the dataset that has a missing value in *any* of the seven columns. There are fancier ways to do this, but I recommend a simple approach like this:

```
data xldata;
    set xldata;
    where cmiss(col1, col2, ..., col7) = 0;
run;
```

The CMISS function counts the number of missing values in the variables you specify at each observation, regardless of the data type. Since we're using WHERE CMISS()=0, the resulting dataset will contain only the records with no missing data for any of the seven columns.

When in doubt, try browsing the [SAS online documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/). It's very thorough.

Answer (score 1):

If you have "SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files" licensed (hint: proc setinit) you can import the Excel file with this code. The where option lets you select which rows you want to keep, in this example you will keep the rows where the column "name" is not blank:

```
proc import 
    DATAFILE="your file.xlsx" 
    DBMS=XLSX
    OUT=resulttabel(where=(name ne ""))
    REPLACE;
    MIXED=YES; 
QUIT;
```

Comment: Since `IMPORT` is not an interactive procedure, the step should be terminated with `RUN` instead of `QUIT`.